# Text Extraction library from different file types, PDF ,DOC, DOCX, TXT c#

Tags: c#, text, information-retrieval

I'm Building Information Retrieval System that search text in multi files formats,
I have Tried **EPocalipse IFilter** Lirary but it through an exception when trying to read **docx** files, and I tried **Toxy** Library it though an exception for **doc** arabic files, finally I tried **TikaOnDotNet** Libray but it need java to work and I need to put the system online on hosting that don't have java installed on server

Comment: I assume you don't want to pay for a 3rd party library - it would be trivial if you did. But if your only blocker is .docx files, [look at this simple c# solution](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOpenXmlGetPlainText-554918c3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using such libraries :

For DOC/DOCX:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/word

For PDF:
https://github.com/itext/itextsharp

For TXT:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

A library which is able to extract all textual data from any type of files is the  [Apache Tika library](https://tika.apache.org/). It can even extract the metadata (if any) from non-text files such as image and video files. Example use cases are shown [here](https://tika.apache.org/1.13/examples.html).

Comment: Thank you my friend I tried to include  TikaOnDotNet in my c# project, I include dll file as a reference in project, and install and include dependencies, but its namespace doesn't able to use. I tried to solve  issue but I cant event I include it in project with NuGet, If you have any idea to solve this issue please share it with me

Comment: If you are having problems with TikaOnDotnet stop by GitHub and open an issue. I'd be happy to take a look. https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet/issues/